# Exchangelib Scan All Folders - Efficiency

Tags: python, exchangelib

I am using exchangelib to connect to my exchange mailbox. Currently the code is scanning through all folders since the target email message can be in any of the folders for my task.

Is there a more efficient way for looping/scanning the folders here? (Looking for emails greater than a target start date)

```py
all_folders = account.root.glob('**/*')
for folder in all_folders:
    # Messages can only exist in 'IPF.Note' folder classes
    if folder.folder_class == 'IPF.Note':
        # For all emails that are newer than the target date
        for email in folder.filter(datetime_received__gt=ews_bfr):
            # Do something
```

Edit:
Thanks for the help, Erik. This worked and made the run time decrease dramatically:

```py
target_folders = (f for f in account.root.walk() if f.name in ['xxxxxx'])
folder_coll = FolderCollection(account=account, folders=target_folders)
for email in folder_coll.filter(datetime_received__gt=ews_bfr):
    # Do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal `.filter()` works on just the folder you call it on. EWS does not support searching items within all folders, but only the folders explicitly mentioned in the `FindItems` service call.

In exchangelib, the way to filter on multiple folders in one go is to use a `FolderCollection`:

```py
from exchangelib import FolderCollection
FolderCollection(account=account, folders=[...]).filter(some_field='foo')
```

The `folders` argument can be any iterable of folders, e.g. `[account.inbox, account.sent]`, `account.root.walk()` or `(f for f in account.root.walk() if f.CONTAINER_CLASS == 'IPF.Note')`

`.glob()`, `.walk()`, `.children` and other subfolder access methods also support calling `.filter()` on them:

```py
account.root.glob('**/*').filter(datetime_received__gt=ews_bfr)
account.root.walk().filter(datetime_received__gt=ews_bfr)
```

Comment: Thanks, Erik. I gave the: `account.root.glob('**/*').filter(....)` a shot but now I'm getting the error:
 `Folders in this collection do not have a common DEFAULT_ITEM_TRAVERSAL_DEPTH value. You need to define an explicit traversal depth with QuerySet.depth() ( {'Shallow', 'Associated'}) ` 
I ran into this when I tried to use the Django (Q) QuerySet in exchangelib too

Comment: This worked. I edited my question with the syntax that worked. Thanks